# How do I solve Kivy error: Bad Window (invalid Window parameter)?

Tags: python, runtime-error, kivy

I installed Kivy and Cython. I am using VirtualBox and Arch Linux with Gnome as my Display Manager. Upon creating the following app,

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class CalcApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CalcApp().run()
```

I receive the following error

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/kyle/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-10-19_40.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.2 (default, Jul 20 2017, 03:52:27) 
[GCC 7.1.1 20170630]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  4 (X_DestroyWindow)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  151
  Current serial number in output stream:  152
```

If I run the command unset DISPLAY it works as intended, but without the option to minimize, maximize and close window that normally are available.

Is there a way to fix this error so I won't need to type unset DISPLAY every time a new terminal window is open and have it look like a normal window?

Comment: I've the same problem - any solution? how do you "unset display" command?

Comment: Using arch, it was "unset DISPLAY" after a month the newest updates changed some things and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved with updates. After about a month I was able to use Kivy as intended with no error.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this issue on Github, it seems likely to be the same problem: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5476

For posterity (and in case the link breaks), it's likely a multi-sampling issue.

Try these fixes:

- Use another desktop environment where the multi sampling works
- downgrade sdl2 to 2.0.5
- upgrade sdl2 to 2.0.7
- disable multisampling in kivy (can be done by editing ~/.kivy/config.ini and setting multisampling to 0